# How to store (cache?) data across multiple sessions in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, caching

I'm writing a C# ASP.NET Web Form Application.  To keep it brief, this application retrieves data from a server and displays it for users.

To access this server, my application needs to generate login info.  Generating login info takes several minutes.  This login info changes daily, but it's the same for everyone who's using my application (on a particular day).

My application will be used by hundreds of people daily.  It's silly for me to make each user wait several minutes for the login info to be retrieved.

Ideally, I'd like to gather the login info once a day, and store the results somewhere on my server.

Any tips?  I know that .NET has `Cache` and `Session`, but those only store data for one individual user.  Do you have any techniques for storing this login info so that I can grab it from my code-behind?

Comment: Can you store the info in the database, and update it using a scheduled external utility or service? I'd think that making ANY user wait several minutes to pull data (through the web-app) is an undesirable solution.

Comment: If you really need performance, take a look at [Redis](http://redis.io/)

Comment: you could also use AppFabric - scalable fast caching system and you can also swap out the standard ASP.NET Session using the AppFabric version without code change but a simple web.config change so it uses AppFabric instead of the standard ASP.NET Session state

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are wrong, the Cache works in the Application level, not in the User level, from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178597(v=vs.140).aspx)

> An application can often increase performance by storing data in
>   memory that is accessed frequently and that requires significant
>   processing time to create. For example, if your application processes
>   large amounts of data using complex logic and then returns the data as
>   a report accessed frequently by users, it is efficient to avoid
>   re-creating the report every time that a user requests it. Similarly,
>   if your application includes a page that processes complex data but
>   that is updated only infrequently, it is inefficient for the server to
>   re-create that page on every request.
>
> To help you increase application performance in these situations,
>   ASP.NET provides caching using two basic caching mechanisms. The first
>   is application caching, which allows you to cache data you generate,
>   such as a DataSet object or a custom report business object. The
>   second is page output caching, which saves the output of page
>   processing and reuses the output instead of re-processing the page
>   when a user requests the page again.

I think the `Application cache` fits better than the other one

**About Expire**

There are two ways to control it, you can set X minutes as limit, and then set if you want :

1. **Absolute**: Expire the data after X minutes since the object was created

   ```
   Cache.Insert("key", myTimeSensitiveData, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1), TimeSpan.Zero);
   ```

> Absolute Expiration: This
>   example will cache the time sensitive data for one minute, at which
>   point the cache will expire. Note that absolute expiration and sliding
>   expiration (below) cannot be used together.

2. **Sliding**:  Expire the data after X minutes since the last user used the cache object

   ```
   Cache.Insert("key",myFrequentlyAccessedData, null, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration,  TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
   ```

> Sliding Expiration: This example will cache
>   some frequently used data. The data will remain in the cache until one
>   minute passes without anything referencing it. Note that sliding
>   expiration and absolute expiration cannot be used together.

Example Source: [MSDN: Caching API, Using the Cache Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx)

Comment: Thank you.  I saw that earlier, and I still don't understand the lifetime of `Cache`.  Does it persist even while nobody's using it?  As in, if my web application has zero users at any point, does the `Cache` delete itself or does it persist in my computer's memory somewhere?

Comment: It would persist even while nobody's using it, until the app pool recycles (which destroys the cache). Look at expiration policy for more control within that limitation. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: If there are a hundred people with a page from a site open in their browser, but nobody has clicked anything in the last half a second, does the site currently have a hundred users, or zero? Really, with HTTP it doesn't make sense to say that there is currently X users. Even if you do something stateful with sessions, it's still considered request by request.

Comment: @JonHanna I think there are a hundred users **logged**, but related to the caching topic, half a second has passed since someone has used the Cache object (if any of them have already used the object cache), so if the time limit is set to 1 minute, in 59.5 secs the data will expire

Comment: Cache would fit the data he's looking to store (so long as the expiration policy of the data, as well as the expiration policy of the app_pool are properly set), but the big gotchya to note here is that Cache is PER worker process. IIS is typically configured to spawn multiple worker processes per app_pool, to better server user requests. Each process would maintain its own cache, and each cache would need to run the multi-minute data retrieval process.